# JAVA - Cassandra ERROR - Codec not found for requested operation

Tags: java, spring, rest, kotlin, cassandra

I want to get all database's IDs. To to that I have to get all databases, and then I'll getId for each database and add it to the list of strings (id is string). But after all I'm getting error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: 
  Codec not found for requested operation: [list<varchar> <-> java.util.Set<java.lang.String>]
```

This is my query at dbrepository:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM db_params")
Result<Database> getAllDatabases();
```

And service to get list of IDs

```
    @Override
public List<String> getAllDatabasesId() {
    Result<Database> databaseResult = databaseRepository.getAllDatabases();
    List<String> listOfId = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Database database : databaseResult) {
        listOfId.add(database.getId());
    }
    return listOfId;
}
```

I dont think that I did something wrong in controller, but here it is:

```
    @GetMapping("/all-id")
fun getAllDatabasesId(): HttpEntity<List<String>> {
    val result = databaseService.allDatabasesId
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result)
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is smth wrong with return in your Controller.

Could you please try smth like that?

> fun getAllDatabasesId(): List =
>               databaseService.allDatabasesId()

Comment: I dunno what happend but it started to works even withouth any changes :D